# woocommerce adding specific out of stock product to direct checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I have two types of products in my store

- one is in stock products
- the other one is on request product. On request product is set as out of stock.

If a user needs an on request product he will will give a request , then from backend we will approve the request then in the oser account page we will give an proceed to checkout button which is an direct checkout .

The issue is if I added the product to checkout page like this ( `Domainname/checkout/?add-to-cart=product id` ) I am getting an error message like this

> You cannot add "product 1" to the cart because the product is out of stock

For checking the validation I have used the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook but its only working if any of  product is there in cart .

Comment: _...for checking the validation i have used the woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation..._ 
It might be useful if you add the code you used for this to your question.

Comment: but its only working if already a product in cart